# Backend update array issue

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am trying to update my database. It went to the correct file but not at the array that I want it to update.

[image: Picture 1] The problem is at line 180-181 (I think). The update went well if I just put **either** one of the code.

[image: Picture 2] It is supposed to update `objmark` in array `tests[1]` and not `objmark` in `tests[0]`.

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Comment: Tried $and as well?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have done that too. It din't update anything

Comment: @Azinuddin: Can you please include the post body you use for this test as in the picture?

Comment: @geckob do you mean the schema or the frontend(the service)?

Comment: you are able to update one of the documents, right?

Comment: @rresol yes indeed. but not the document that I want

Comment: How are you sending the requests for updating, via some script ?

Comment: Look if you are sending requests using the script and using loops then that can be the problem.

Comment: @rresol this is the first time I'm using stacoverflow. sorry for any confusion. This is my service:
 
$http.post(Constants.BASE_URL + '/candidate/savetest', {
           user: user,
           mark: mark,
           ans: ans,
           testname: testname,
           testLevel: testLevel
     }, auth.getAuthHeader()).then(function(response) {
           deferred.resolve(response.data);
           console.log(response.data[0]);
           }, function(err) {
           deferred.reject(err);
           });
           return deferred.promise;

Comment: @rresol is that what u asking for?

Comment: @rresol yes. but it's okay. I've solved the issue